# Segmentation Fault 11 when adding two 2D arrays using structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have been working on a program that does math on matrices, and decided to create a struct containing the information required to do the calculations:

In matrices.h:

```
 struct Matrix{
  int x; //x
  int y; //y
  int **matrix; //hold matrix values
 };
```

I can print out the values of a matrix using the output command:

```
void output(struct Matrix* matris){
int c,d;
for (c=0;c<matris->x;c++){
    for(d=0;d<matris->y;d++){
        printf(" %d ",matris->matrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n Press any key to continue...");
scanf("%d",&c);
}
```

This function however, fails with segmentation fault 11, where the addition takes place.

```
 void doAddition(struct Matrix* moutput, struct Matrix* matrixa, struct Matrix* matrixb){
  int c,d;
  for(c=0;c<matrixa->x;c++){
    for(d=0;c<matrixa->y;d++){
        moutput->matrix[c][d] = (int)matrixa->matrix[c][d] + (int)matrixb->matrix[c][d];
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Error log:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000100200000
0x0000000100001392 in doAddition (moutput=0x7fff5fbff800, matrixa=0x7fff5fbff820, matrixb=0x7fff5fbff810) at matrices.c:109
109 moutput->matrix[c][d] = (int)matrixa->matrix[c][d] + (int)matrixb->matrix[c][d];
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer… a segmentation fault indicates that you're accessing illegal memory, that is, memory that is not part of the arrays you're working with.  Can you step through your code with a debugger and determine exactly where the segmentation fault is occurring?

Comment: Your code will crash if matrixb's x or y dimension is smaller than matrixa's corresponding dimension, as you're just looking at matrixa's size, could that be the problem?

Comment: There is validation on the x and y, so they will always be the same, but the code crashes on this line: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000100200000
0x0000000100001392 in doAddition (moutput=0x7fff5fbff800, matrixa=0x7fff5fbff820, matrixb=0x7fff5fbff810) at matrices.c:109
109    moutput->matrix[c][d] = (int)matrixa->matrix[c][d] + (int)matrixb->matrix[c][d];. However accessing the same matrices and just using printf, works fine.

Comment: Put this error log to the question. It is unreadable as comment.

Comment: Added error log to main post

Comment: Does this work for a symmetric matrix (e.g. x=y=2)?

Comment: I was testing using symmetric and asymmetric matrices, both of which fail with a seg fault.

Comment: Why do you cast here: `moutput->matrix[c][d] = (int)matrixa->matrix[c][d] + (int)matrixb->matrix[c][d];`?

Comment: How do you *know* `readIn` works?

Comment: Just to make sure that it was not a cast error

Comment: I know readIn works, as I can readIn, and then output, and it displays the matrix exactly as it was typed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo:

This line in `doAddition()`

```
for(d = 0; c < matrixa->y; d++){
```

shall be

```
for(d = 0; d < matrixa->y; d++){
```

**Hint**: Allow youself more "spaces", this enhances readability and with this reduces the risk of misreadings.

**Hint^2**: Learn how to use a debugger (for example [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)), and use it. It'd have given you the possiblitly to inspect the variable's values around the line the program crashed.

Comment: Thank you so much! For the life of me I couldn't see that!

Comment: @Escalion: You are welcome. But heed my advices as per my answer. Also regular breaks from coding might help.

Comment: I will indeed, I've only just started getting used to gdb recently, do you have any pointers on using it?